# How Do I Pass a Specific Ethereum Address to an Async Load Contract Function?

Tags: javascript, ethereum, web3js

```
async function loadContract(address) {
    return await new window.web3.eth.Contract(abi, address);
}

async function load(address) {
    await loadWeb3();
    window.contract = await loadContract(address);
}
```

/*
I pass in the address from the frontend but because it's async it is not reading    the input... I have multiple contracts and need to be able to interact with a specific one based on user input
*/

Comment: what's the issue with code you posted - does it work as expected? perhaps you're trying to access `window.contract` before it's assigned a value? you need to know how to work with asynchronous code

Comment: Creating a Web3 is synchronous. Creating a contract instance is synchronous aswell. As far as i know there is no asynchronous implementation of these two functions

Comment: I forgot to mention that the frontend connects to MetaMask, which requires async functions. The problem does not occur otherwise.